# How does memory splitting work with mmap() and virtual memory?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, mmap, virtual-memory

### Forepart:

1. Assume we're on a 32bit Linux OS, with 4GB of physical memory.
2. There is no swap partition!
3. There's a kernel, reserving 200MB of non-pageable memory which cannot be taken by anyone else (this whole statement is only my assumption and you may correct the value or state that kernel doesn't do that).
4. At time t₀ there are three processes `p1`, `p2` and `p3` consuming 1GB of physical memory.
5. Now a 4th process starts which `mmap(2)`s 4GB of memory with `MAP_PRIVATE` of an empty file, with `PROT_WRITE`! This process starts a `for` loop, writing some value to each element of this `mmap`ed array; like this:

   ```cpp
   for(int i=0; i<4GB; i++)
       mmap_array[i] = i*i%255;
   ```

---

### Question:

1. When process `p4` has written data up to 2.8GB, asking to write the next byte, does kernel halt the other 3 processes, create a image of them, and since there is no swap, store them back into RAM; Which again consumes 1GB of physical memory (because they had 1GB of RAM when they were running, so same image size)?
2. If above question is a YES, does it mean that if a process asks for more memory, which is held by others, there will be context switch?
3. Regarding how page fault works, from now on, since this 1GB couldn't be freed and available RAM is still 2.8GB, when `p4` asks for the next element of array, does kernel unload the very first page, and then load new page instead of unloaded page?
4. If the 3th question is a YES (which I doubt) how does the kernel keep the value of that unloaded page whose physical memory is to be used by this new page? (There's no swap partition; would it force disk swap space anyway?)
5. What if it was `MAP_SHARED`? Would the value of the unloaded page be carried through the backing file, and then the physical space get freed?
6. When a process like `p4` does that (or other cases when RAM gets 100%) why system hangs? Is it because it needs extra space to restore those images of `p1`, `p2` and `p3`? Or those will be restored in that 1GB, but as soon as they ask for more memory, they'll freeze?
7. Again if #6 is a YES, and those 3 processes used `MAP_SHARED` couldn't or do they act as #5? Continue but slow (only one page of RAM at the time)?
8. `SysRq` still works; does it mean every process will hang, but since kernel has reserved memory, it won't?

---

The reason why all these questions came all together in one post is by understanding all these, I'm able to understand the actual question which is the one I wrote in title!

I just numbered the things I'm looking to get answer for, to avoid commenting on answers people write.

Comment: There's quite a lot of "it depends" for any answer to this.  A lot depends on whether memory overcommit is enabled, in which case the `mmap()` call may succeed and the process later get killed by the out-of-memory handler.  Actually `mmap()` will fail if a 32-bit process asks for 4GB, because that's more memory than it can address, so we won't even get to that point.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for your words; Alright I edit the question and make it 3.9 GB?
As for the over-commit case (with `MAP_PRIVATE` if I understood correctly) what you wrote is actually an answer itself. So if over-commit is enabled, how would it do? asks for the next page even there is no space, then because there is no space to store unloaded page, and over-commit new page, it gets killed? Doesn't over-commit mean it shouldn't unload any page? why it gets killed then because of low mem?

Answer (score 2):

Let me introduce you to the "Linux Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer" https://rakeshjain-devops.medium.com/linux-out-of-memory-killer-31e477a45759

Basically the Linux kernel does maintain a score of "sacrificability" for each and every process, and if it ever encounters are situation where it cannot fulfill a memory allocation, it will sacrifice processes in order of the score, to make space.

If push comes to shove, the process that attempts a mmap-ed write that can not be done, because no matter how hard the kernel tries to make space, eventually that process will get raised a SIGBUS (bus error, bad memory access) signal.

Comment: Great answer, I appreciate your time. So enlighten me, as comment on original post said, if there's `MAP_PRIVATE` with over-commit enabled, when memory is full even after it tried to make space as you said, what happens? I mean what's the word over-commit suggest if it gets killed when there is no memory and no backed file? Does it need swap?

Comment: It will receive a SIGBUS signal, which essentially means, the program will be forcefully crashed. SIGBUS is a cousin to SIGSEGV, but where a segmentation fault is caused by a programming error, a bus error is the result of a fault outside the programmers control.

Comment: Understand that, but I mean what's the purpose of over-commit? What does it do and intended for? Can you please clarify? Both the purpose and how it tries to do that underlay.

Comment: @Shahaboddin: The reason for overcommit is, that many memory allocators (i.e. the things on which malloc, new, etc.) are built will operate on larger pools of pre-"allocated" mmap MAP_PRIVATE regions, but then at runtime often only a much smaller fraction is used. In tools like `htop` this can be seen in the discrepancy between *VIRT* and *RES* stats. *VIRT* is what's been mmap-ed, but *RES* is, what's actually used in memory. Overcommit allows to utilize resources more efficiently. Without overcommit a lot of memory would be reserved, but never used.

Comment: @Shahaboddin: There are of course certain system configurations, where you – the system's owner / administrator – knows from experience or theoretical reasoning, that memory that is requested will also be used. In this case it is recommended to disable memory overcommitment. Without memory overcommit, it's the `mmap` call that will fail (with `MAP_FAILED` return value) if the requested amount of address space can not fit into the available memory resources.

Comment: So it's the over-commitment that makes it possible to handle VM larger than available physical memory by raising page faults.

Comment: If the answer to my above (last) comment is yes, the question #3 (where I asked does it unload very first page (for example) to make space for the newly requested page when kernel cannot make any more space), it's wrong, am I correct? You said when there cannot be anymore space freed, and process requests to actually access physical memory, it gets SIGBUS.
Did I understand correctly?
And without over-commit, `mmap` cannot even begin with mapping address beyond available free RAM?

Comment: @Shahaboddin roughly yes. The details are somewhat more complicated, of course; for example same page merging (=deduplication) and since recently memory compression also somewhere in the loop. But in the gist of it… yes.

Comment: As last comment here, "But in the gist of it… yes":
 1. Did you mean YES, in very simplified speaking, kernel unloads one page from the start of the map, and add newly requested page to the end of map;  
 2. Or you meant oherwise (no, it doesn't unload anything and just send SIGBUS)?  
If it's the first case, why would it need to kill it? it can continue doing that; and we're back to question #4.
I very much appreciate all your effort here, helping in such a kind way; I didn't mark it as answer since I still have unanswered question.

Comment: @datenwolf Thank you again, if you could add anything or answer my comments, please, go ahead.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: I'm not referring to the SIGBUS being sent by the OOM killer. I'm referring to the SIGBUS being sent to the process that causes a page fault to a mapped but not resident address, which can not assigned a physical page due to lack of resources. Basically such faults are "reported" the same way, faulty memory is. And yes it can be caught and dealt with (important in high reliability systems).

Comment: @datenwolf ah makes sense, sorry for the mix up.